# “Quality cannot be tested in” idiom

Tags: idioms

Please explain to me the meaning of an idiom “Quality cannot be tested in”.

The context is as follows (from the book *How Google Tests Software*):

> “Quality cannot be tested in” is so cliché it has to be true. From automobiles
>   to software, if it isn’t built right in the first place, then it is never going to be right. Ask any car company that has ever had to do a mass recall how
>   expensive it is to bolt on quality after the fact. Get it right from the beginning or you’ve created a permanent mess.

Comment: It means that quality must be *designed in*.  Simply testing the device extensively will not greatly improve quality (though certainly some testing is necessary to achieve ultimate quality).

Comment: Here's at least [one instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22High+quality+cannot+be+tested-in+by+the+end+user%22) where the writer went to the trouble of hyphenating to help the reader parse *tested-in, designed-in, manufactured-in*.

Comment: Quality cannot be tested in; it has to be [built in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/build?q=build+in#build__10).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you please further explain this lexical pattern, when "-in" is added to a verb?

Answer (score 4):

“Quality cannot be tested in” means, "Testing your product after it has been built, no matter how many times you do so, isn't going to add quality to your original design; build it right the first time and it will pass every test."

Or, "Testing after the fact is not a replacement for designing and building it correctly in the first place."

Comment: @cloud_nine: It's really just an ad-hoc "made-up verb", based on usages such as *We **design in** quality* (we design our products in such a way as to ensure that they reflect quality). So *to test in quality* would mean to *test in such a way as to cause the product to be [high] quality*. Except apparently you can't do this because by then it's too late (you *have* to design it in - if the quality isn't already there, no amount of testing will cause it to appear). As for the preposition itself - that's just normal English (you can also *design **for** quality,* for example).

Comment: To intentionally misquote the 1982 Ford television commercial, today I think that ***"Quantity*** **is Job One."**

Comment: Mark - watch out for early symptoms of *grumpy-old-man-ism* there. Personally, I think the high visibility and ease of posting of customer feedback on sites like eBay and Amazon (and the "trusted broker" status of the site as an intermediary) almost certainly make it more likely that inferior quality products will be quickly identified and shunned today.

Comment: Hahahaha! http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB106749964360204600 **and** http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/gm-recall/gm-recalls-about-3-2-million-cars-ignition-problems-n132511 **and** http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-07-24/fiat-chrysler-recalls-1-4-million-autos-to-defend-against-hacks **and** http://www.nydailynews.com/autos/news/toyota-recalls-1-6-million-cars-faulty-takata-airbags-article-1.2450202 **and** http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/a10794/gm-recalls-another-8-2-million-vehicles-16944031/ **and** http://money.cnn.com/2012/10/10/investing/toyota-recall/ Shall I keep going? :-)

Comment: FF- The feedback systems in place on eBay and Amazon are brilliantly successful, the first rating vendors and the second rating products. Too bad there isn't a readily available system for ***your third largest purchase*** after buying a house and paying for your children's education. (*Consumer Reports* tries but often fails to identify defects in current model cars.) Grumpy? Me? (I love all your comments and answers and look forward to them every day!)

Comment: Sadly, I think you're probably right that most Westerners spend more on cars than on making financial provision for retirement. My working life ended prematurely a few years back, and what with other unexpected setsbacks, I haven't exactly ended up in the circumstances I might have hoped for. But at least I can wake up every day (*midday*, if I'm honest! :) and be grateful I'd made *some* progress.

Comment: FF- So true and me too! I wish we had kept our older Subaru Forester instead of buying a used Infiniti, and banked the extra money for retirement. Had I known I was going to have to retire on disability at the age of 60, we surely wouldn't have bought that car. Like quality, the future cannot be "tested-in" either. With kind regards,